# Disable Skype "Update your Background Apps setting" notification without disabling all Skype notifications

Tags: windows-10, skype, notifications, skype-for-windows-10

Whenever I put my Windows 10 device into battery saver mode, I get the following message:

[image: Skype notification]

> #### Update your Background Apps setting
>
> You may be missing Skype calls and messages due to your current settings.

If I go to the Windows Settings app, I only see an option to disable *all* notifications from Skype, which I don't want because I do in fact use Skype. The Skype app itself doesn't provide a setting to disable just this notification. (I'm using the Windows Store app.)

Can I disable this annoying toast notification without disabling any other Skype notifications or functionality?

Comment: You can disable Skype from running in the background in *Settings > Privacy > Background apps*.

Comment: @harrymc: Please reread the question. I don't want to disable Skype itself or any functionality other than that notification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you receive this message is because Windows automatically prevents Skype from running as a background process in Battery saving mode.

To prevent this message and conserve all functionalities, follow these steps:

1) Go into **Settings**. Then select **System**. Afterwards, select **Battery**

2) On the top, under the battery life estimate, you will see a choice named **Battery usage by app**. Select this.

3) This will give you a list of apps and their impact on the battery. Find Skype in this list.

4) Select Skype and uncheck the choice written **"Let windows decide when this app can run in background"** (I use a french OS, so the exact text may differ.)

5) Then underneath, select the choice written **"Authorize this app to run in background."**

Skype will now be able to run without limitations even on battery saving mode. The message discussed above will no longer be displayed when switching to power saving mode.

*Note that this applies only from Windows 10 version 1607 and higher. I highly suggest updating windows if you have an earlier version.

Edit: You cannot disable a single notification in Windows 10. It is either all the notifications are enabled or disabled for a single app or service.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to suppress this notification only, without changing anything about whether Skype is allowed to run in the background?

Comment: There is no way of disabling a single notification in windows 10. You can only disable an app completely from notifying you. There is no inconvenience of letting Skype always run in the background, besides a very small increase in power draw.

Comment: This is good enough for me, so I'll award the bounty.

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to do so, but I guess this is the only proper fix so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to explicity say that this notification is coming from the Skype app, and not from Windows per se. As @Natsu stated, when your computer enters power-saving mode, Windows prevents (at least some of) Skype's functionality from running - the intention being, to conserve the battery power that Skype would otherwise use. The Skype dev team has obviously  decided to counteract this a little, and so Skype detects when this happens and notifies the user to let them know that they could potentially be missing calls/messages.

So, that leaves you with a few options...
You can:

1. Accept the situation, and essentially ignore this Skype notification, which can't be turned off within Skype individually
2. Disable *all* Skype notifications entirely - Windows allows you to enable/disable notifications on a per-app basis
3. Uninstall Skype
4. Prevent your computer from ever going into power-saving mode
5. Allow Skype to run fully in power-saving mode

The last option is probably the one you want. See @Natsu's answer for how to do that. Theoretically, your battery will be depleted faster because Skype is using additional power, but you're probably headed for a power outlet at this point anyway, so you probably won't mind if it runs fully in power-saving mode.